# Is there a way to get a Total column in crosstab (frequency table) with multiple columns in Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I need a **total column** next to my side index (**Center_Name**). There's margins function in crosstab, but it is limited to one column only . I have the following code to have multiple columns in a crosstab, but unable to add a total column.

The code I'm using(Deriving data from Excel):

```
cols=['Gender','QAge_Post']
q2=(nb.melt(id_vars='Center_Name',value_vars=cols)
       .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Center_Name'),'value'])
       .size()
       .unstack(fill_value=0))
q2
```

I have 50 rows with columns Center_Name, Gender, QAge_Post. I'm using Center_name as index and the remaining two as columns.

The output:

| Center_Name | 18 - 25 Years | 26 - 35 years | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Delhi | 8 | 5 | 3 | 10 |
| Kolkata | 2 | 6 | 4 | 4 |
| Lucknow | 7 | 5 | 5 | 7 |
| Mumbai | 0 | 11 | 2 | 9 |
| Pune | 3 | 3 | 5 | 1 |

I need a **total row** in the end as well

Comment: please provide data in `pd.DataFrame(<put your data here>)` in this format for faster resolution, fancy tables may not be needed :)

Comment: Hmm. The data I'm drawing is in Excel form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with select only `Male` and `Female` columns for `sum` and also [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for `sum` for new row:

```
df.insert(0, 'Total', df[['Male','Female']].sum(axis=1))
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
print (df)
             Total  18 - 25 Years  26 - 35 years  Male  Female
Center_Name                                                   
Delhi           13              8              5     3      10
Kolkata          8              2              6     4       4
Lucknow         12              7              5     5       7
Mumbai          11              0             11     2       9
Pune             6              3              3     5       1
Total           50             20             30    19      31
```

Comment: Thank you. But can I also get a total row at the end.

Comment: @BenjaminRoy - I miss it, now added to solution

Comment: Thank you.  Was just going to post the same solution I figured out. `df.loc['total'] = df.iloc[:].sum()`. But yours is way better!